# Give a digital signature after friend request to use after to prove friendship in social apps?

Tags: security, social-networking, bigdata

I am building some kind of social app with the concept of 'friends' where friends can do actions regarding one or more of their friends, 
I would rather not ask the DB if the friendship does exist every time someone sends any kind of request for an action.
An idea I came up with is after a friendship is approved a digital signature will be sent to each user which can be checked in the server for each request which should cost less than asking the db.
Then I can maybe change the async key everyday or so and force the user to ask for a new digital signature in which case I do approach the db to test friendship (it's good for security but also a must if users want to cancel friendships).

What I ask is if this is a terrible idea? Maybe I'm not seeing something. Or just any link to any information about these kind of scenarios would be great.

Comment: I have read some more info since about using cryptography methods instead of db calls. I still haven't found anything regarding my usecase. I did however see that it might be better to send a time limitation in the friendship signature that represents until when the signature is valid instead of changing my crypto key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of handing out a digital signature can be done, though I am not sure if it would actually be any faster then querying the database, seeing as databases are meant to be incredibly fast.

Lets move on with the idea that it is indeed a good idea. You would need a token of sorts that has the information about who is your friends and it has to have been validated by the server. This, to me, seems like something you could use a JSON Webtoken (JWT) for.

[Here is the basics on JWTs](https://jwt.io/).

JWTs have three parts to them: Header, payload and signature. The header defines how long the token will be valid for and the payload can contain the list of friends (or IDs of friends). The signature is a hash of the entire thing, signed with the private key of the server, thus verifying that the server has approved this token as valid until time X. The entire thing is encoded before sending.

You would then send the JWT in a HTTP header of some sort, probably the `Authorization` header. The server could then quickly decode the JWT (there are libraries for this in a lot of languages, JWTs are a pretty good standard) and thus not need to query the database. The size of the JWT does need to be send though, and thus I am not sure you will actually gain any speed from this.

Comment: Thanks. I think using JWT will benefit me. One reason is that I can separate the servers that handle the chat and other actions between friends from the servers that handle the issuing of friendships. This way I can scale my db accordingly. I can do the same for sessions using jwt then I can disregard the db all together in these servers.